# How to show Items data in base currency instead display currency in PDF Invoice?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, invoice, multicurrency, invoice-pdf

How to i can show Item price and subtotal in base currency instead Display currency in Pdf Invoice Magento 2 ?

I have call rest data in Base currency But facing issue on items data.

Kind Regards

[image]

Comment: You need to do the customization here by overiding the file.

Comment: I am already overriding this file, but that code which will show base currency of  items price and subtotal. just looking to that.

Comment: share the code.

Comment: Thanks @DhirenVasoya. I have resolved my issue with this code.
$this->getOrder()->getBaseCurrency()->formatTxt($item->getBaseRowTotal())

Answer (score 0):

To Convert any Amount to Base Currency, you can use this code.

```
class MyConvertPriceClass
{
    protected $_priceHelper;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper) 
    {
        $this->_priceHelper = $priceHelper;
    }

    public function MyFunctionconvertToBaseCurrency($price)
    {
        $formattedCurrencyValue = $this->_priceHelper->currency($price, false, false);
        return $formattedCurrencyValue;
    }
}
```

Now you can call `MyFunctionconvertToBaseCurrency` with price which you want to convert.